# maximum numbers in js

Tags: javascript, html

How to make my input maximum 10 digits length.How to make possible to enter only 10 numbers.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="return isAllowedSymbol(this); checkNumbers(this);" "placeholder="Enter data" name="answer" ><br>

  function checkNumbers(input)
    {   
     if (input.value.length > 10)
        {
         input.value = input.value.replace(input.value, '');
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works already, but you have a syntax error - I removed the extra quotation mark.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="return isAllowedSymbol(this); checkNumbers(this);" placeholder="Enter data" name="answer" >
```

Comment: What's not working?  The maximum length is 10 so the condition in your keyup function will never be true.  Also make sure your javascript is enclosed in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it with `maxlength="10"`, you have quotes messed up though. JS is redundant.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter data" name="answer" ><br>
```